# Inductor in a series LR circuit

Tags: resistance, inductor

What's could be the impact of the internal resistance of an inductor on a series LR circuit?

Comment: It adds to the external R.

Answer (score 2):

As a model of a real inductor, suitable for relatively low frequencies, well below the self-resonant frequency, you can consider the real inductor as an ideal inductor in series with a resistance equal to the internal resistance.

The actual situation is that the resistance is distributed throughout the inductance but that doesn't matter provided the capacitance doesn't come into play too much.

So your model of the inductor looks like an ideal inductor in series with a resistor, and the external resistor is also in series.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvGUds.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So if you analyze this circuit (a low pass RL filter) you'll find a -6dB attenuation at low frequency because of the voltage divider R2/(R1+R2) and the -3dB down frequency (-9dB total) will be more like 32kHz than the 16kHz you'd expect with an ideal inductor.